# unable to map data from JSON in render method, empty screen on emulator

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I am successfully getting data from API and also am able to pass the object as props in the next component, my code for passing object is:

```
if (stateItems.length > 0) {
        console.log(stateItems[0]);
        if (stateItems[i + 1]) {
            items.push(
                <Grid key={i}>
                    <Product key={stateItems[i].product_id} product={stateItems[i]} />
                    <Product key={stateItems[i + 1].product_id} product={stateItems[i + 1]} isRight />
                </Grid>
            );
        }
    }
```

In the receiving end when i console log this.props.product I can see my data: [image]

but when I try to render the data I get an empty screen, my code for rendering the data is:

```
render() {
console.log(this.props.product)
return (
  <Col style={this.props.isRight ? style.leftMargin : style.rightMargin}>
    <Card transparent>
      <CardItem cardBody>
        <Button transparent style={style.button} onPress={() => this.pressed()}>
          <Image source={{ uri: this.props.product.image }} style={style.image} />
          <View style={style.border} />
        </Button>
      </CardItem>
      <CardItem style={{ paddingTop: 0 }}>
        <Button style={{ flex: 1, paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }}
          transparent
          onPress={() => this.pressed()}
        >
          <Body>
            <Text
              style={{ fontSize: 16 }}
              numberOfLines={1}
            >{this.props.product.name}</Text>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', alignItems: 'center' }}>
              <View style={style.line} />
              <Text style={style.price}>{this.props.product.price}</Text>
              <View style={style.line} />
            </View>
          </Body>
        </Button>
      </CardItem>
    </Card>
  </Col>
);}
```

Comment: you are having an array of data, right? then iterate over it to show

Answer (score 0):

As per you show `this.props.product` look like its `array of object`.

You need to use `map` for `iterate` array and display product.

```
this.props.product.map((singleProduct, index) => {
    return (
        <Col style={this.props.isRight ? style.leftMargin : style.rightMargin}>
<Card transparent>
  <CardItem cardBody>
    <Button transparent style={style.button} onPress={() => this.pressed()}>
      <Image source={{ uri: singleProduct.image }} style={style.image} />
      <View style={style.border} />
    </Button>
  </CardItem>
  <CardItem style={{ paddingTop: 0 }}>
    <Button style={{ flex: 1, paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }}
      transparent
      onPress={() => this.pressed()}
    >
      <Body>
        <Text
          style={{ fontSize: 16 }}
          numberOfLines={1}
        >{singleProduct.name}</Text>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <View style={style.line} />
          <Text style={style.price}>{singleProduct.price}</Text>
          <View style={style.line} />
        </View>
      </Body>
    </Button>
  </CardItem>
</Card>
    );
})
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the problem? because it still isn't working, empty screen is still there

Comment: Please just print only single  row so you may get some more ideay.

this.props.product.map((singleProduct, index) => {
    return (
<Text>{singleProduct.name}</Text>
);
})

And let me know.